# Delphi Create Maximized MDI Child with AnimateWindow

Tags: delphi, mdi

I have an application with MDI forms, and i've been trying to make an Child creation effect, with `Animatewindow()`.

My question is, all my MDI forms are with `Windowstate=wsMaximized`, and don't know how to create the form without showing the default classic window resize AND with the animation...

This is what i'm trying:

```
procedure FORMCREATOR(t_form:tformclass);
var form:tform;
begin
    frmain.sPanel5.Hide;
    frmain.LockClientWindowUpdate;    
    form:=t_form.Create(frmain);
```

// btw, if i do "t_form.Create(application)" instead of "t_form.Create(frmain);" it gives an error.. and with the "....(frmain)" i cant access the form like "form.button1.caption:='test'" outside this procedure, Access violation! .. help plox!

```
    frmain.UnlockClientWindowUpdate;  

    AnimateWindow(form.Handle,500,AW_CENTER or AW_SLIDE or AW_VER_POSITIVE); 
end;
```

So, when i call this, it just create the form like there was no `Animatewindow()`... it is only shown maximized with no effect :( ..

Guys please give me a little hand ! 
Thanks.

Comment: no answer since not uasable as it is, but perhaps a playgroud:    With TForm4.Create(self) do
    begin
      Formstyle := fsNormal;
      visible := false;
      Width := Application.Mainform.ClientWidth ;
      Height := Application.Mainform.ClientWidth;
      Parent := self;
      AnimateWindow(handle,2000, AW_CENTER or AW_SLIDE or AW_VER_POSITIVE );
      Parent := nil;
      FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
    end;

Comment: Works like a charm.. but i made some modifications to the code, and i want to post the solution.. but i need to wait 8hours? :/

Comment: Yes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89063/answering-own-question-now-has-8-hour-limit  but there is no need to hurry ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @bummi 's idea..

I changed to this:

```
procedure tfrmain.FORMCREATOR(t_form:tformclass);
var form:tform;
nome_form:string;
begin
    frmain.sPanel5.Hide;       

    frmain.lockClientWindowUpdate;

    With t_form.Create(frmain) do
    begin
         visible := false;
         Formstyle := fsNormal;   //Now i'll make all my forms as fsnormal  
         Parent := self;

         Width := frmain.sPanel5.width; 
         Height := frmain.sPanel5.height;       
         left:=frmain.sPanel5.left;
         top:=frmain.sPanel5.Top;
```

//This Spanel5 is the supposed client area where will be the MDI child, thats why i hide it at the beggining of the procedure

```
         frmain.UnlockClientWindowUpdate;

         AnimateWindow(handle,1000, AW_CENTER or AW_SLIDE or AW_HOR_NEGATIVE );

         frmain.lockClientWindowUpdate;

         Parent := frmain;
         FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
         windowstate:=wsmaximized;

         frmain.unlockClientWindowUpdate;
    end;    
end;
```

And.... Yes ! It works perfectly, no image flickering and such things !! ;) Thanks a lot!